# get Azure computer instance name from within the VM

Tags: azure

Is there a way to get the instance name on Azure VM. 
I would like to get it from Windows, not from Rest API/API.
The instance name is same as the computer name that shows in Azure portal, but its not the actual computer name from Windows, since Windows computer name can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this isn't *easily* possible.

There is a very basic metadata service available on Azure at (http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/maintenance) but it only gives details of imminent downtime. It is (was!) hoped that it would expand into something useful, but there's no sign of that.

My particular solution was to create a small (free would be fine) Web API service that has access to subscription credentials and can search through the subscriptions to find the incoming IP Address, and then feed back its data.

It is something of a hack, but it gives what is needed.